# DOMException Error when trying to play audio in Vue.JS App

Tags: vue.js, domexception

I want to play a music file with a click of a button, but I am thrown this error:

```
DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

This is the button that calls the play music function:

```
<button  v-on:click="playMusic()">Play Song</button>
```

This is my play music function:

```
playMusic: function() {
                var audio = new Audio("../../media/KR881.mp3");
                audio.play();
            },
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the rule to your webpack.config.js in order handle audio files by webpack

```html
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.mp3$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules(?!\/foundation-sites)|bower_components/,
                options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
            }
        ]
    }
```